# Creating a sample data table with X, Y, Z axis (student, cours, score) to bind to grid

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I am trying to create a data table to bind to a grid for demonstration purposes:
X axis column: "StudentName" (string)
Y axis column: "CourseName" (string)
Z axis column: "Score" (double)

The user has to be able to edit both the student names and the course names (so these will have to be regular fields not column headers). I will most likely be hiding the actual columns and displaying the first row as the student names. The main thing I can't figure out is how Z will be its correct data type.

**I figured it would go something like this:**

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("BRIAN", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("SARAH", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("JIM", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add("", "BRIAN", "SARAH", "JIM");
        table.Rows.Add("SCIENCE", .5, .2, .5, .6 );
        table.Rows.Add("ENGLISH", .5, .2, .5, .6);
        table.Rows.Add("MATH", .5, .2, .5, .6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display structure you are trying to achieve isn't how you would set the information out within a data set

You could then cut/ Slice the data any way you like for displaying purposes

Quick way of displaying to the grid
Create an object -> put the data in to a collection of those objects -> bind to the grid

```
public class ReportScores(){
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int EnglishScore {get;set}
        mathscore etc etc
}
```

Create a `List<ReportScore>`

Bind the list to your grid, Flat layered grid with all the information per student

In my experience grids like you are trying to achieve can sometimes be harder to read

Thanks

Truez

Comment: So your saying I should initially set my datatable up like you did because that is most likely how the data will come from the database. Then format the datatable to dynamically show the students at the top, the subjects along the left, the scores all in between??

Comment: personally I wouldn't lay the grid out how you are because you are going to cause yourself a lot of hassle, I'll edit my answer